# How to display the recent user revision in a views block with contextual filters?

Tags: users, views, uri

We are having a Setup where we need to be able to display User Revision Fields via Views Blocks. We are using the [User Revision Module](https://drupal.org/project/user_revision) and even fixed a Bug on the Contextual Filter Plugin of that Module.
Lets say the Url is /user/abc/revision/123 everything with a Contextual Filter for the VID on the Path works fine.
The Problem comes when we want to display the last Revision trough the same View because it has not the Revision Url pattern. it is only user/abc
Do i have to write a custom Contextual Filter which can differentiate the Url ? And what is then used instead of the VID ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using PHP Code in the contextual filter:

```
$cpath = explode('/',current_path());
$path_uid = $cpath[1];
if (array_key_exists(3, $cpath)) {
  $path_vid  =  $cpath[3];
  return $path_vid;
}
else {
  $result = db_query("SELECT vid FROM {user_revision} u WHERE uid = (:uids) ORDER BY vid DESC LIMIT 0,1", array(':uids' => $path_uid))->fetchField();
  return $result;
}
```

Would be nice to put this in a custom module so if have to make changes and do not have to touch every display of the view.